# Копирование файлов из/в телефон android

Tags: delphi, eclipse, android

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как программно скопировать файл из/в телефон android(среда разработки Eclipse или Delphi).

поясню свой вопрос, у меня есть программа написаная на delphi ей необходимо скопировать файл на компьютер, произвести над ним операции, а потом снова скопировать в телефон

Comment: Надо добавить метку android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы работаете c ADT Plugin for Eclipse, то никаких дополнительных действий по копированию, установке и запуску приложения на Android телефон делать не надо: Eclipse все сделает сам. Но кроме Eclipse, можно явно использовать Android SDK.

Чтобы установить приложение на телефон, выполнить команду

```
adb install приложение.apk
```

Чтобы переписать файл на телефон, выполнить команду

```
adb push файл место
```

Чтобы переписать файл с телефона, выполнить команду

```
adb pull место файл
```